Flatlist onViewableItemsChanged gets blocked when using a sticky header
Currently, I am trying to implement a header that appears when scrolling up and disappears when scrolling down, but when I place my header element inside of StickyHeaderComponent, the logic inside of onViewableItemsChanged( checks if the user has scrolled near the bottom by seeing the index of the post currently being viewed and if it is, the next batch of posts gets reqeusted) stopped executing(when scrolling it acts as if the items currently viewed haven't changed) and because of that I can't call my API for more items.
This is the FlatList with the it's viewabilityConfig:

  const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
    viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 20,
    waitForInteraction: false,
  }).current
 
        <Animated.FlatList
          className="w-full"
          style={{
            zIndex: 1
          }}
          data={data?.pages.flat()}
          keyExtractor={item => {
            return item._id
          }}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [
              {
                nativeEvent: {
                  contentOffset: { y: scrollY }
                }
              }
            ],
            {
              useNativeDriver: true
            }
          )}
          onViewableItemsChanged={({ viewableItems }) => {
            const lastVisibleItem = viewableItems[viewableItems.length - 1];
            if (lastVisibleItem) {
              const { index } = lastVisibleItem;
//Checks if the last viewed item was near the bottom and if it is the next batch of posts gets requested
              if (index >= data.pages.flat().length - 3) {
                fetchNextPage();
              }
            }
          }}
          viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
          StickyHeaderComponent={() => (
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                zIndex: 10,
                position: "absolute",
                height: HEADER_HEIGHT,
                transform: [{
                  translateY: Animated.add(scrollY, diffClampScrollY.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, HEADER_HEIGHT],
                    outputRange: [0, -HEADER_HEIGHT],
                    extrapolate: "clamp"
                  }))
                }]
              }}
              className='w-full bg-[#0F0F0F]'
            >
            </Animated.View>
          )}
          stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
          renderItem={(item) => {
            return (
              <PostItem>
              </PostItem>
            )
          }}
        />

